# Error handling async pipe - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

We are trying to see how can we do error handling using the async pipe. We know how to do it if we subscribe to the http `GET` request, but we aren't subscribing to it. Do I have to do it using `.pipe`?

**TS**

```
getAmountDue(equipment: Equipment[]): Observable<PickupAvailability> {
    return this.http.post<PickupAvailability>(
      this.BASE_URL + this.AMOUNT_DUE_URL,
      equipment
    );
```

**HTML**

```
{{ testAmountDue$ | async }}
```

Comment: have you checked out the docs? https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling  is there something in particular you are looking for? pipe is one way to go, interceptor is another... just not sure what you're looking to do.

Comment: @AndyDangerGagne OMG there are so many. I guess for this simple POST request I will end using pipes. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to answer my own question since I found the solution,to solve my problem I decided to use the **.pipe** solution based on this **POST** request being a very simple request.

First we write an error handler like the following:

**TS**- pickup-availability.service.ts

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
  // return an observable with a user-facing error message
  return throwError(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
};
```

Notice that this handler returns an **RxJS ErrorObservable** with a user-friendly error message. Consumers of the service expect service methods to return an Observable of some kind, even a "bad" one.

Now you take the **Observables** returned by the **HttpClient** methods and pipe them through to the error handler.

**TS**- pickup-availability.service.ts

```
 getAmountDue(equipment: Equipment[]): Observable<PickupAvailability> {
        return this.http.post<PickupAvailability>(
          this.BASE_URL + this.AMOUNT_DUE_URL,
          equipment
        ).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
 }
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling